# Having hard time to understand why this function is called MapReduce

Tags: scala, dictionary, reduce

In my [Scala course](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) an example has given. It was about finding a more generalized function, which can be used to define an arithmetic summation function and an arithmetic production function. Here are the functions that should be generalized.

```
def sum(f:Int=>Int)(a:Int,b:Int):Int ={
 if(a>b) 0
 else f(a) + sum(f)(a+1,b)
}

def product(f:Int=>Int)(a:Int,b:Int):Int={
 if(a>b)1
 else f(a)*product(f)(a+1,b)
}
```

To generalize these functions the teacher gave such a function :

```
def mapReduce(f:Int=>Int,combine: (Int,Int)=>Int, zero:Int)(a:Int,b:Int):Int ={
    if(a>b) zero
    else combine(f(a),mapReduce(f, combine, zero)(a+1, b))
}
```

So mapReduce function can be used to generalize sum and product functions as follows:

```
def sumGN(f:Int=>Int)(a:Int,b:Int) = mapReduce(f, (x,y)=>(x+y), 0)(a, b)
def productGN(f:Int=>Int)(a:Int,b:Int) = mapReduce(f, (x,y)=>(x*y), 1)(a, b)
```

I took a look at the definition of map reduce in functional programming but I have a hard time why the generalized function has been named as map reduce above. I can not grasp the relation. Any help will make my very happy.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by no means an exact explanation (names are fuzzy anyway) but here’s an alternative definition:

```
def mapReduce(f: Int => Int, combine: (Int, Int) => Int, zero: Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int ={
  if (a > b) zero
  else (a to b).map(f).reduce(combine)
}
```

Do you see the link?

Answer (score 5):

Functional programming usually has three central operators: `map`, `reduce` (sometimes called `fold`), and `filter`.

- Map takes a list and an operation and produces a list containing the operation applied to everything in the first list.
- Filter takes a list and a test and produces another list containing only the elements that pass the test.
- Reduce (or fold) takes a list, an operation, and an initial value and applies the operation to the initial value and the elements in the list, passing the output into itself along with the next list item, producing the operational sum of the list.

If, for example, your list is [2,3,4,5,6,7], your initial value is 1, and your operation is addition, reduction will behave in the following way:

```
Reduce([2,3,4,5,6,7], +, 1) = ((((((initial + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5) + 6) + 7)
```

Your instructor may be calling it `mapReduce` because this is the paradigm's name, though simply `reduce` would be sufficient as well.

If you're curious as to the significance of his name, you should ask him.  He is your instructor and all.

Comment: The example is from on-line video course. It's hard to ask the instructor.

Comment: I don't know that, and since you're not the OP, I'm not sure you do either.

Comment: @AntonSizikov if you talking about Coursera course, I've seen that Martin (instructor) sometimes answers on questions on forum

Comment: @Wug , the course refers to coursera, I could ask it there to the discussion forum, however I have a strong evidence that coursera scala community is the subset of the SO scala community :)) I got more efficiency asking the question here. And thanks to all who answer the question. Regards

Comment: @cgon: Shows what I know.  Can you link to the course in the question?

Answer (score 1):

mapReduce's mapping function is f in the question, though there's never an example of its definition.  For sum and product it would be the identity function, but if you were summing the squares then the mapping function would be the square function.

mapReduce's reducer function is combine, wherein we are reducing a tuple of accumulator+value to a new accumulator for the next recursion.

I think the missing link besides the code not being very clear is to treat numbers as collections (e.g., 3 is a collection of three 1s).  This is quite unusual and I don't know what it buys you but it could be that your teacher will use the analogy between numbers and collections for something more profound later.

Is this from Odersky's coursera course?